# Unable to read contents of QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having some issues with Qt with c++ and reading the contents of my scene, here is my current code:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, ui->graphicsView->scene()->items()) 
{
    item->setVisible(false)
    qDebug() << item->x();
}
```

Currently this code is able to set all the items in my scene to invisible which is great however the query for all the item coordinates returns a 0 for every item in the scene. I feel I have some stupid mistake with pointers but I'm lost here currently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if a item is invisible it will not be possible to query for coordinates, for all effects it's just like if it was removed from the scene.

Comment: Even If I remove the setVisible line the X coordinate is still returned as 0.

Comment: how did you created the objects?

Comment: The only objects contained in the scene are created with the addEllipse function.

Comment: and you didn't answered my question. how are you calling the addEllipse function?

Comment: I think I know what's happening. you created the ellipse via addEllipse but never called setPos() on the ellipse created, and because of that the original position of the Ellipse will be (0,0), even if you create an ellipse in (20, 50, 100, 100); it's position will be 0,0 because the (20,50,100,100) are in internal coordinates of the ellipse.

Comment: Ah ha I think you have it, I'll fix up my other code and see if it resolves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: just a tip - try to make your ellipses like this(-50, -50, 100, 100) - do the calculations so 0,0 is in the center of the ellipsis, then it's easier to know how to position it in the scene.